# converting jquery to pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that creates an image with the canvas object. The last line of the function says this:

```
$('body').css({ 'background-image': "url(" + Canvas.toDataURL("image/png") + ")" });
```

I'm looking to convert this line into pure javascript to remove the jQuery dependency. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+Canvas.toDataURL('image/png')+')';
```

Comment: Don't forget that IE doesn't like `style`, and uses `cssText`.

Comment: I've never had any issue with IE and `.style.property`. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html